# Matplotlib 3d surface example not displaying correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to produce a 3D surface plot using matplotlib.  As a starting point i've copied the [example provided in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html).

Rather than looking like the example in the above link, it looks like this:
[image: like this]

I'm using Windows 7, Python 2.7.3 and Matplotlib is version 1.5.1. What could I change to have my surface plots appear as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using matplotlib version 1.5, you need to refer to the example of this version, instead of the one for version 2.0:

https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html

The difference is that you need to specify `rstride=1, cstride=1,`:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```